# Long forum threads; split into x pages parts or let them go on endlesslly

Tags: user-research, forum

I have a forum going on and I find that users keep talking on and on in certain threads.

It feels like clutter to me, seeing threads that are 600 pages long, but it does not seem to bother my users.

As I see it, I have 3 options.

1. Let them talk. Who cares how many pages the threads are, they just
   jump to the last page anyway.
2. After an x amount of posts, automatically archive the previous posts
   into an archive thread. There will be a link in the top of the
   thread to view the archive. This way the original link is preserved.
3. After an x amount of posts, automatically close the thread and
   create a "part 2" with a link to the new thread after the last post
   (so, at the bottom of the thread).

What would you do?

Comment: Option 4: introduce the concept of "moderator" that will delete, move and stop off-topic messages, eventually creating new threads when required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We used to have moderators on the forum, but  they tended to be too strict. That costed me a lot of visitors back then. I suppose I will have to be very careful in chosing moderators in the future. Until then, I will do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users are happy. There is no need to do anything. Option 1!

Everything you do will make them unhappy.

Comment: Thanks for the backup. I have started a poll on the forum to simply just ask my users what they want. Nobody minded the million pages, they are taken to the newest posts anyway when clicking a topic. So yes, I have indeed decided to let it be. What was it again... never change a winning team.